# Spacy: Retain position markers in string, ignore them in Spacy

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I'm running rather long documents through Spacy, and would like to retain position markers of paragraphs in the Spacy doc but ignore them in the parse. I'm doing this to avoid creating a lot of different docs for all the paragraphs.

Example using XPath:
`\\paragraph[@id="ABC"] This is a test sentence in paragraph ABC`

I'm looking for a bit of direction here. Do I need to add entities/types or implement a customized tokenizer? Can I use the matcher with a callback function to affect that specific token?

### Your Environment

- **Installed models:** en
- **Python version:** 3.4.2
- **spaCy version:** 1.8.1
- **Platform:** Linux-3.16.0-4-686-pae-i686-with-debian-8.6

Answer (score 3):

spaCy's tokenizer is non-destructive, so you can always find your way back to the original string -- text[token.idx : token.idx + len(token)] will always get you the text of the token.

So, you should never need to embed non-linguistic metadata within the text, and then tell the statistical model to ignore it.

Instead, make the metadata a standoff annotation, that holds a character start and end point. You can always make a labelled Span object after the doc is parsed for your paragraphs.

Btw, in order to keep the alignment, spaCy does have tokens for significant whitespace. This sometimes catches people out.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! I get what you're saying, but my challenge is that I my input is in XML format, and I need to be able to relate Spacy's doc back to that XML. 

1. If I extract text-only from XML, I lose the relationship between the original XML-standoff and Spacy's indices. 
2. If I incorporate the XML, Spacy analyzes it.
3. If I pre-process the XML (for example as a dictionary of standoffs: text) my performance drops dramatically because I need to create SpacyDocs for each paragraph.

Comment: Why can't you have (text, standoffs), for the whole text? Each standoff would map (start, end) character offsets to the tag name and attributes. Then you can retrieve a span from the spaCy doc that the tag enclosed.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your suggestion. Would my input be the raw XML? If so, wouldn't that mess up the doc.sents and the parse result? I'm not interested in parsing any of the stuff inside the XML tags, I just need to be able to translate Spacy's doc back to the XML.